# Create stacked page with panels module

Tags: 7, panels, theming

I'm trying to create a stacked page with the [Panels](http://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module, using flexible layouts. It should look like this:

[image: Stacked page]

How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to DA :) If you post a link to the image (preferably an imgur link) then someone can edit it in for you :)

Comment: Have you considered creating the three rows as mini-panels? The main page panel can then be a single column layout.

Comment: I'm fairly certain I've answered a very similar question before. The magic word here is "layout", try searching for information on how to create new panels layouts, and I think you'll find something.

Comment: I've already made some panels layouts, but I don't know how I can use multiple of them at the same time on a page.

Comment: @Jeroen The image you've posted can be __a__ layout. Why would it be multiple ones?

Comment: @Letharion: well, I succeeded in creating 3 different layouts (one for every 'row'), but I don't know how I can put them together. It would be perfect if I could create just 1 layout like you say.

Comment: There must be some low-level miscommunication here, as I don't at all understand what the problem is. Just stick all the code in the same file?

Comment: O, I understand why you are confused. I created the layouts with 'flexible layouts', I didn't code them. Should I do that instead?

Comment: Aha, there we go. You should add that to the question. :) The flexible layouts should mostly be considered quick prototyping tools. If they are useful in their own right, that's great, but they have limits. With that said, can't you do the same thing in one flexible if you just start with a single wrapper that will encapsulate all three rows?

Comment: Oooh, it's indeed that simple! I didn't know that one could add multiple rows above each other in a flexible layout: I was so busy working with the regions that I didn't think about that anymore. Thank you so much to show me my silly mistake!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add 3 rows in the flexible layout by clicking **'Column' > 'Add row to top/bottom'** in the layout designer to stack the page. Add fluid or fixed regions afterwards in every row.

(Special thanks to @Letharion!)

You can also achieve this without the flexible layouts and do it programatically like @Andrew Welch said. [This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmX2jnH9Kdg&desktop_uri=/watch?v=gmX2jnH9Kdg&app=desktop) can help you in doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a panels layout. You can find these in the panels module in the layouts folder. I believe you can then create a layouts folder in your theme and copy a layout in there, and work on it. Layouts are simply an includes file with an array of options, a template file, and a thumbnail image.